# Is there a way to change what Pepper says in Autonomous Life?

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I would like to change what Pepper the robot says when it is in "default mode", i.e. without having any application launched; thus enabling it to answer some questions the manufacturer didn't include, or to change its answer.

I have already tried —to no avail— looking for a solution on Aldebaran's documentation, google researches proved fruitless too.

The kind of questions that the robot can be asked are here: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/family/pepper_user_guide/basic_channel_conversation_pep.html it doesn't say how to change the content though.

I'm basically expecting the robot to be able to deliver some information without needing to get into application; I'm aware that there are collaborative speeches but this isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: What is your motivation for not getting into application?

Comment: My motivation is that the robot is mainly used at my company's office, it has some collaborative topics I'd like to access from "default mode" at launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1:

You can find the dialoges from Pepper at:

```
/data/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/dialog_*
```

e.g.

```
/data/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/dialog_goodbye/dlg_goodbye/dlg_goodbye_enu.top
```

You could edit or extend those.

### Option 2:

You could copy the content, edit them as you like and merge it into your own dialog.
But you would have to "get into application".

If you just want to add something to the default dialoges. Then you could activate your own custom topic in default mode.

Given your topic file is named `myTopic.top` and is placed in `/data/home/nao/`:

```
import naoqi
from naoqi import ALProxy
ald  = ALProxy("ALDialog", "pepper.local", 9559)
myTopic = ald.loadTopic("/data/home/nao/myTopic.top")
ald.activateTopic(myTopic)
ald.getLoadedTopics("English")
```

Then your custom topic should be listed among the other topics activated in defaut mode.

### Option 3:

Make your own application with your own dialog and just activate all the other topics too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply TVK. I this normal that I don't find the .local folder though? https://imgur.com/a/GmlRHLG

Comment: yes, it is hidden... just type "cd .local" or to go there directly just type "cd /data/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps"

Comment: it worked for me, was able to display all the list of apps. I just need to figure out how to download the files from the cmd window and everything should be okay. You've been of a great help

Comment: welcome! for file transfer try winscp if you are using windows or a linux equivalent.
small changes can also be done in the cmd window directly using vi or nano

Comment: I went for Filezilla in the meanwhile; it did the trick for me, I was able to access everything and edit it. Forgot to edit my above post, sorry about that